# Yahoo email client not applying css to <img> element with embedded CSS

Tags: html, css, email-client, email-templates

HTML email template i am sending to the Yahoo client does not have CSS applied to the `<img>` elements:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
      .image1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .image2 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .container {
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="someimage1.jpg" class="image1" />

    <div class="container">
      <img src="someimage2.jpg" class="image2" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Yahoo client, `img` elements need to have `id` attributes with CSS that we want to apply.

**Solution:**
I added same `id` names as the `class` and just added in the CSS that same CSS properties apply to them.

NOTE:
I left classes present, just to be sure if some other client messes with `class` on some other elements:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <style>
      .image1,
      #image1 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;
      }

      .image2,
      #image2 {
        width: 100px;
        height: 50;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      .container {
        background: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="someimage1.jpg" class="image1" id="image1" />

    <div class="container">
      <img src="someimage2.jpg" class="image2" id="image2" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Elaboration**
The issue was, that Yahoo client strips CSS that are referred in the `image1` and `image2` classes for `<img>` elements. Not sure why, but this only happens for this `img` tag.

Most of the email clients transfer embedded CSS into inline, and for Yahoo, it seems they are not transferring onto `<img>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. You need to write inline CSS. And also for most email clients it is always recommended to write table-based html. And you also have to avoid a lot of CSS rules that doesn't work for emails. Like here, `border-radius` will not work in Outlook. So when writing CSS you can also check what [CSS property you can use for emails](https://www.caniemail.com/).

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img src="someimage1.jpg" width="100" height="100" style="border-radius: 50%;"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red">
              <img src="someimage2.jpg" width="100" height="50" style="margin: 0 auto;"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for covering the `border-radius` one. Did not know that

Comment: Glad to know that helped :)